# CoreData & NSDate - date stores 1 day behind in 2015

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I'm really stumped on what should be something really simple. A feature of my app is to have monthly repeating events, so I need to take a Date, add a month to it, and store it. Each month I repeat this.

The problem I'm having is that I've found whilst testing that when the date gets past March 2015 it loses a day - so 22nd March becomes 21st March...April...May etc .The even stranger thing is once I get past March 2016, it just switches back to 22nd - no longer missing a day.

It can't be daylight savings because it occurs over a 12 month period, or Leap year because 2015 isn't a leap year, as far as I'm aware.

I'm using MagicalRecord to help with CoreData, and I'm pretty sure it might have something to do with CoreData itself? Here's the simple code called to update the date:

```
// create date if we haven't already
    if (!_dateEntity.theDate) {
        NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
        _dateEntity.theDate = date;
    }

    NSLog(@"date before update - %@", _dateEntity.theDate);

    // add a month to it
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setMonth:1];
    _dateEntity.theDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:_dateEntity.theDate options:0];

    NSLog(@"date after update - %@ \n ***** \n", _dateEntity.theDate);

    // save the context
    [[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (success) {
            //NSLog(@"You successfully saved your context.");
        } else if (error) {
            //NSLog(@"Error saving context: %@", error.description);
        }
    }];
```

This is semi-sudo code, stripped out from the actual project into a stand alone project just to test (to make sure I'm not going mad!)

Here (as requested) are the logs from xCode:

```
2014-07-23 10:48:55.001 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2014-07-23 09:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:48:55.003 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2014-08-23 09:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:48:59.994 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2014-08-23 09:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:48:59.995 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2014-09-23 09:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:04.685 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2014-09-23 09:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:04.686 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2014-10-23 09:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:08.127 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2014-10-23 09:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:08.128 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2014-11-23 10:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:12.594 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2014-11-23 10:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:12.595 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2014-12-23 10:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:16.014 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2014-12-23 10:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:16.015 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2015-01-23 10:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:20.188 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2015-01-23 10:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:20.189 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2015-02-23 10:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:32.956 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2015-02-23 10:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:32.957 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2015-03-23 10:48:54 +0000 
 ***** 
2014-07-23 10:49:44.061 dateTest[52136:60b] date before update - 2015-03-23 10:48:54 +0000
2014-07-23 10:49:44.061 dateTest[52136:60b] date after update - 2015-04-23 09:48:54 +0000 
 *****
```

From the logs, everything looks fine - still on the 23rd (today). However, if I actually look in the database itself, the last two dates 2015-03-23 and 2015-04-23 appear as 2015-03-22 and 2015-04-22 respectively.

The latest update in the Database, as shown in the SQL browser is:
2015/04/22 10:48:54

They'll behave like this until March 2016, at which point they will go back to being stored correctly. This is the bit that I really don't understand.

Anyone ever experienced something like this? I'm tearing my hair out right now

Comment: Could you please log your `_dateEntity.theDate` before and after adding a month, and then add the results as an update to the post?

Comment: Sure, just done for you. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please post those last two dates 2015-03-23 and 2015-04-23 as they appear in database but also with time and time zone?

Comment: ok mate, that's in the post now - but here as well The latest update in the Database, as shown in the SQL browser is:
2015/04/22 10:48:54

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what about timezone? Did you managed to get it from the database? The might be no issue actually, just log's and database's date might be the same date but with different timezones.

Comment: hmm, I can't find the timezone anywhere in the database - it's not being logged in the NSDate object itself. Does the Database as a whole have a timezone too? If it does, and you think that would help figure out whats going on, could you help me locate it?

Comment: Dates are wrong when you look in SQLite yourself or when you use SQL Browser. What do they look like if you use Core Data? That's what actually matters here.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it really is a Daylight Saving Time problem, not a Core Data problem. Your time interval computation gives you unexpected results when the interval straddles the change date to or from standard time to DST.

Try this example, free of Core Data:

```
    NSDate *dateNow = [NSDate date];

    // add a month to it
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [components setMonth:1];
    components.calendar = calendar;
    NSDate *dateNowPlusOneMonth = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:dateNow options:0];

    NSLog(@"now %@", dateNow);
    NSLog(@"now plus one month %@", dateNowPlusOneMonth);

    NSDate *dateMarch01 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1425206934];
    // add a month to it
    NSDate *dateMarch01PlusOneMonth = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:dateMarch01 options:1];
    NSLog(@"Interval straddles ST/DST changeover date in USA");
    NSLog(@"March 01 %@", dateMarch01);
    NSLog(@"March 01 plus one month %@", dateMarch01PlusOneMonth);

    NSDate *dateMarch23 = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:1427107734];
    // add a month to it
    NSDate *march23PlusOneMonth = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components toDate:dateMarch23 options:0];
    NSLog(@"Interval is after ST/DST changeover date in USA");
    NSLog(@"March 23 %@", dateMarch23);
    NSLog(@"March 23 plus one month %@", march23PlusOneMonth);
```

Here's the output (with NSLog timestamps removed):

```
now 2014-07-23 18:03:22 +0000
now plus one month 2014-08-23 18:03:22 +0000

Interval straddles ST/DST changeover date in USA
March 01 2015-03-01 10:48:54 +0000
March 01 plus one month 2015-04-01 09:48:54 +0000

Interval is after ST/DST changeover date in   USA
March 23 2015-03-23 10:48:54 +0000
March 23 plus one month 2015-04-23 10:48:54 +0000
```

To add to the dastardly nature of this problem, you'll see different results in your program, depending on the timezone (really DST change dates) of the user. Australia, the UK, and the USA will all have slightly different error behaviors!

Listing 10 of the Date and Time Programming Guide illustrates "Getting the Sunday in the current week". I think you'll need to adapt that procedure, something like "getting the current date and time in the next month".